# Use specified css file for HtmlEditorExtender design view?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

Does anyone know of a way to make the HtmlEditorExtender use a specified css file to display its content in design view?

I am replacing occurences of FreeTextBox, which has a DesignModeCss attribute that accepts a file path. By using that I could make the design mode use the css of the public part of the site, while editing from within the content management system which has its own style sheet.

It would be nice if something similar would be possible with the HtmlEditorExtender as well.